# Valid Regex Specifict name pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

i'm dealing with a regex to validate an specifict name patter, but i have no  results so far, i'm using javascript and the idea is to match any name with this pattern:

```
screenshot1.png
```

it could be screenshot0.png, screenshot3.png, screenshot99.png but alway with the same pattern i'm using

```
^(screenshot[0-9].png*)$
```

but if i write screenshot9.pn (with out the g) it shows as a valid string.

Comment: Try `^screenshot[0-9]+\.png$` using a quantifier for the character class, escape the dot to match it literally and you can omit the `*` after the `g` or else that would repeat the `g` itself 0+ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, all you need is to remove the `*` at the end and let the regular expression match more than one digit after the `screenshot` word and escape the `dot` because `dot (.)` is a special meta-character that will match [almost any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html):

```js
const tests = ["screenshot09.png", "screenshot09.pn", "screenshoot.png", "screenshoot999apng"];

tests.forEach(x => console.log(/^(screenshot[0-9]+\.png)$/.test(x)));
```

Also, If you want to capture all the pattern with a global scope on some text, you can use `g` option of the regular expression and removing `initial (^)` and `end ($)` delimiters:

```js
const test = "I have screenshot09.png and bad screenshot09.pn and screenshot with no number: screenshoot.png and this nice one screenshot123.png";

console.log(test.match(/(screenshot[0-9]+\.png)/g));
```

Note, that also you can replace the pattern `[0-9]+` by `\d+`.

Answer (score 2):

this will match what you want also you can add any extension you want `(png|jpeg|...)` in case you want anything .png jpeg here is : `\w*\.(png|jpeg)`

```js
const regex = /screenshot\d*\.(png|jpeg)/g;

const text = "dfgkdsfgaksjdfg screenshot541.png screenshot999991.jpeg"
const res = text.match(regex);

console.log(res)
```